# Create subdomain for each registered user (java EE)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, subdomain

How do I create subdomain like http://user.mywebsite.com ? Is it actually simply possible to create it via pure java/java EE code or I need to use some external script-server side language?

To those who answered: Well, then, should i ask my hosting if they provide some sort of DNS access??

Comment: It's a configuration issue unrelated to Java. You should understand how reverse proxies work, then ask your hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

With a reverse proxy server, in front of your application server, it's possible with some configuration, see http://www.jvmhost.com/articles/host-random-wildcard-subdomains-tomcat-java

You can know which subdomain a request is coming from using `request.getServerName()`.